# how to display the number 1 each time user accesses the page

Tags: php

I have a problem when it comes to displaying the correct number in my heading. When a user submits a page and navigates to this current page, I want the heading below to appear:

CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 1 OF  3

As you can see it above it starts with the number 1 as the user is creating their first session. The problem I am getting is that it never displays number 1, it just keeps displaying this below:

CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 3 OF  3

It keeps displaying the number 3 which is incorrect as if the user enters the current page for the first time then obviousl they don't start with session 3, they start with session 1, then 2 then 3.

So my question is how do I get "SESSION 1" to be displayed when the useer enters the page for the first time?

Below is the current code I have:

```
  if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
                //Declare my counter for the first time

                $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
                $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];

        }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])) {
        $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
        ++$_SESSION['sessionCount'];
    }


    $sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];

...

    <h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: why is `$_SESSION['initial_count']` and `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` set to the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting for the first time:

```
//Declare my counter for the first time
$_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
```

Set it to 1! Because after that `isset` will return true, and so, it will not be set to 1...

```
//Declare my counter for the first time
$_SESSION['initial_count'] = 1;
```